# C# - File Watcher as a windows service watching multiple directories

Tags: c#, windows, service, filesystemwatcher, directory

I have a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for. I am writing a file watcher Windows Service in C# using FileSystemWatcher. I would like to watch multiple independent directories, I have the directories to watch and some other settings in a xml file. The program reads in the xml, creates the appropriate number of FileSystemWatchers and stores these system watchers in a dictionary with a randomly generated id number (as the keys). The problem that I am having is that only the first FileSystemWatcher is responding to files being created/deleted/updated ect. I know the others have been create because the entries are in the dictionary. I know EnableRaisingEvents = true because all of the  FileSystemWatcher are created the same way via a loop. I have no idea how to get multiple file watchers working correctly, and I would like to avoid threads if possible. If anyone has any ideas or resources to look at, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hard to see what may be wrong if you don't show any code...

Comment: The concept works.  I just wrote a console app that listens to two directories successfully.  (Perhaps you configure one watcher over and over but have many watchers in the hash)  PS - Your reasons for "I knowing" are very weak.  You only know what you can see with a debugger or trace output to be true (and even that only when the planets aren't mis-aligned)

Comment: You can try looking at this sample at codeproject, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271669/Using-FileSystemWatcher-to-monitor-multiple-direct

Answer (score 0):

Im afraight you háve to instantiate some kind of thread pool or task factory because a filewatcher can only watch one file in a thread.

However this posting has a very nice example of doing so:
[How to assign separate thread for each File System Watcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317966/how-to-assign-separate-thread-for-each-file-system-watcher)

Hope this helps